# Matrix class with std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, matrix

I want to build a simple matrix class. The relevant part of my header file looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class matrix
{
private:
  unsigned int nrows;
  unsigned int ncols;
  std::array<std::array<T, ncols>, nrows> mat;

public:
  matrix();

  unsigned int getCols() const;
  unsigned int getRows() const;

};
```

The problem here is that the two-dimensional array (called mat) needs the number of rows and columns. Obviously, this doesn't work but I don't know how to solve this issue.

My source file:

```
template <typename T>
matrix<T>::matrix() : nrows(0), ncols(0) {}

template <typename T>
unsigned int matrix<T>::getCols() const {
  return ncols;
}

template <typename T>
unsigned int matrix<T>::getRows() const {
  return nrows;
}
```

The initialization of a matrix should look something like this:

```
matrix<double> my_matrix;
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::vector>` `std::array<std::array>` dimensions must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You cant have variable size argument for `size` of `array`. Therefore you must have two more template arguments for `matrix` class.

```
template <typename T, size_t ROWS, size_t COLS>
class matrix
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I've implemented the class with std::vector now due to the need to push_back etc.